# Running into Error - 1004 'Application Defined or Object Defined Error' with using PasteValues

Tags: vba, excel

Running into error 1004 trying to copy and paste the cell values over themselves (to eliminate formulas and just get the values). Works fine when I record it on the sheet, alas it doesn't work when I implement it in my subroutine. Error occurs on the `PasteSpecial` line:

```
If i = ws_count Then
    'ws_count - 2 allows us to place the new tab before the last sheet in the data file (admin)
    Sheets(twomonthsago).Copy Before:=Sheets(ws_count - 2)
    Sheets(twomonthsago & " (2)").Name = lastmonth & " test"
    Sheets(twomonthsago).Cells.Copy
    Sheets(twomonthsago).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
End If
```

I've also tried directly selecting `Range("A1")` before pasting, still getting the error. All my variables have valid strings assigned to them so that isn't the issue.

Comment: You can do `Sheets(twomonthsago).Cells.PasteSpecial ...` too

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assign it directly.

Replace these:

```
Sheets(twomonthsago).Cells.Copy
Sheets(twomonthsago).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
```

With:

```
With Sheets(twomonthsago).UsedRange
    .Value = .Value
End With
```

Comment: Uh oh, got an "Out of memory" error after trying that.

Comment: Voila, that fixed it! Thanks a bunch. Congrats on breaking 50k btw.